# What's the easiest way to switch multi-window apps?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I got the 7.0 Nougat upgrade yesterday, and loving the new Multi-Window support. However, I can't find a way to easily switch the positions of the two apps.

The quickest way I found to switch them was to do this:

1. Drag divider all the way up to close Multi-Window with the bottom app as the only app
2. Hold apps button to restart Multi-Window, putting the only app on top
3. Select latest app to put it on the bottom

Is there any hidden way to do this in a single step, like a long hold, triple tap, anything like that?